# Bash - pause and resume a script (for-loop) with certain key

Tags: bash, shell-script, for, read

I am using the following counter functionality in a script:

```
for ((i=1; i <= 100; i++ )); do
    printf "\r%s - %s" "$i" $(( 100 - i ))
    sleep 0.25
done
```

is there a way I can pause and resume the counter with keyboard input?
(preferably with the same key - lets say with <kbd>space</kbd>)

Comment: Control-S, control-Q?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `read` with a timeout `-t` and set a variable based on its output.

```
#!/bin/bash

running=true

for ((i=1; i <= 100; i++ )); do
    if [[ "$running" == "true" ]]; then
        printf "\r%s - %s" "$i" $(( 100 - i ))
    fi

    if read -sn 1 -t 0.25; then
        if [[ "$running" == "true" ]]; then
            running=false
        else 
            running=true
        fi
    fi
done
```

With this, you can press any key to pause or unpause the script.

`running` stores true or false to tell if we want the loop to do work or now. `read -sn 1 -t 0.25` is the key, it reads one character `-n1`, it suppresses keypresses `-s` and waits for only 0.25s `-t 0.25`. If `read` times out it returns a none 0 exit status which we detect with the `if` and only if a key was pressed do we toggle the status of running.

You can also assign the read char to a variable and check for a specific character to limit it to only one key.

```
    if read -sn 1 -t 0.25 key && [[ "$key" = "s" ]] ; then
```

Use `"$key" == ""` if you want to check for space or enter.

Note that one side effect of the read + timeout is that if you hit a key the next loop will execute quicker then normal which is made more obvious if you hold down a key.

An alternative might be to use job flow control. `ctrl + s` will suspend a terminal and `ctrl + q` will resume it. This blocks the entire shell and does not work in all shells. You can use `ctrl + z` to suspend a process giving you a prompt back and use `fg` to resume the process again which allows you to continue to use the shell.

Comment: good idea if timing is not important for application.

Comment: I only can upvote once, so "Thanks, again for the update!"